# What is the best/better place for asking questions about GKE/Kubernetes

Tags: discussion

I have recently posted a few questions on GKE/Kubernetes deployment issues to ServerFault and StackOverflow. [A first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38473823/can-kubernetes-service-mount-multiple-portions-of-a-single-gce-disk-at-the-mul) has been downvoted and voted-to-close, presumably because it was not strictly about programming, although StackOverflow apparently hosts many other questions on GKE/Kubernetes operational issues as well. (I have later cross-posted/migrated [the same](https://serverfault.com/questions/790938/can-kubernetes-service-mount-multiple-portions-of-a-single-gce-disk-at-the-mul) question to ServerFault.)

So here is my meta question: What is the best/better place for asking  questions about GKE/Kubernetes deployment (etc.) in terms of site rules and size of expert audience? There seem to be more such questions/answers present on StackOverflow. I have received more answers on ServerFault so far. Or is best way forward to open GKE-Kubernetes-related questions as [issues](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues) on GitHub as many seem to do? Has there been any "official" communication e.g. from Google on this matter?

Comment: [so] has a long standing bad habit of upvoting and answering good questions that belong here. ... And of trying to send questions here that don't belong or are utter crap. I gave up trying to understand this.

Answer (score 4):

Quite a few topics overlap somewhat and are on topic and suitable for the audience found at either ServerFault and StackOverflow.

You can always [flag](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) your own questions for migration to the another site if you don't get a (good) answer on your first choice.

Please don't cross post your questions on both ServerFault and Stack Overflow though.

Comment: As OP I now agree that flagging own question for migration is better than cross-posting (which I only did once so far).